# Android menu icon animated to an arrow when drawerLayout open

Tags: android, android-animation, android-toolbar

I've noticed lately that many new android apps uses this Material style for toolbar menu, where the menu icon (the one defined with `mToolbar.setNavigationIcon()`)  is those three straight lines ( [image]) , and when the user opens the side menu (`DrawerLayout`) the lines turns to an arrow in a continuous fashion (animated). As I've seen it already in the android versions of [outlook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.outlook&hl=en) and [wikipedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wikipedia&hl=en) I started thinking it might be a built-in theme/icon-set etc, and not a proprietary implementation, but I can't find anything in the documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

New drawer toggle is available in appcompat v7 library, version 21+

Use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` class instead of     `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` when creating drawer toggle.